# Aurelia-animator-css fadeIn effect

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, aurelia

I'm trying to get the aurelia-animator-css library working with my app and not having any luck. I've got a template with a structure like this:

```
<div id="droplets" class="col s4 au-stagger" style="min-height:655px;">

    <div id="droplet-1" class="droplet-1 droplet-left au-animate" ref="droplets[1]">
      <div style="height:25px;"></div>
      <p>Droplet 1</p>
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
    </div>
    <div id="droplet-2" class="droplet-2 droplet-right au-animate" ref="droplets[2]">
      <div style="height:10px;"></div>
      <p>Droplet 2</p>
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
    </div>
    <div id="droplet-3" class="droplet-3 droplet-left au-animate"  ref="droplets[1]">
      <div style="height:20px;"></div>
      <p>Droplet 3</p>
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the droplets to fade in one at a time like is shown in this blog post: http://blog.aurelia.io/2015/07/17/animating-apps-with-aurelia-part-1/ , but I'm having no luck.

Here's the SASS I'm working with so far:

```
@-webkit-keyframes dropletFadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes dropletFadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

#droplets {
  .au-stagger {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 50ms;
    animation-delay: 50ms;
  }
  #droplet-1,#droplet-2,#droplet-3 {
    &.au-enter {
      opacity: 0!important;
    }

    &.au-enter-active {
      -webkit-animation: dropletFadeIn 2s;
      animation: dropletFadeIn 2s;
    }

    &.au-leave-active {
      -webkit-animation: fadeOut 2s;
      animation: fadeOut 2s;
    }
  }
}
```

So far it does nothing. I've also tried using the animator directly like this:

```
attached() {
    setTimeout(() => {this.showDroplet(2)}, 750);
    setTimeout(() => {this.showDroplet(3)}, 1500);
    setTimeout(() => {this.showDroplet(1)}, 2250);
  }

  showDroplet(num: number) {
    this.log.debug('Showing droplet ' + num + ' element = ' + this.droplets[num]);
    // this.droplets[num] = true;
    this.cssAnimator.addClass(this.droplets[num],"dropletFadeIn").then(successful => this.log.debug('Did it work for ' + num + '? ' + successful));
  }
```

Also with no luck... it does nothing and the Promise returns false. I've also had the droplets use an if.bind to put them into the DOM after the page is rendered to trigger the animator, and that didn't work.

Anyone have any ideas?